# ChainLink Keepers not performing upkeep

Tags: hardhat, chainlink

So I've created a contract which programmatically registers Upkeeps. The Upkeep is successfully being registered (I can see it on the website) and is funded well above the minimum balance, however the upkeep doesn't seem to be working.

Also, I am able to call the "perform upkeep" function by myself, so I know that that's not the issue. Here is the code for the Keepers functions:

```
function checkUpkeep(
        bytes memory /* checkData */
    )
        public
        view
        override
        returns (
            bool upkeepNeeded,
            bytes memory /* performData */
        )
    {
        bool isOpen = (s_gameState == GameState.OPEN);
        bool timePassed = ((block.timestamp - s_lastTimeStamp) > interval);
        upkeepNeeded = (isOpen && timePassed); 
    }

    function performUpkeep(
        bytes calldata /* performData */
    ) external override {
        (bool upkeepNeeded, ) = checkUpkeep("");
        //require (upkeepNeeded, "Conditions not met");
        if (!upkeepNeeded) {
            revert Game__UpkeepNotNeeded(
                address(this).balance,
                s_holders.length,
                uint256(s_gameState)
            );
        }
        s_gameState = GameState.CALCULATING;
        uint256 requestId = i_vrfCoordinator.requestRandomWords(
            gasLane,
            _subscriptionId, //check sub ID here
            REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS,
            callbackGasLimit,
            NUM_WORDS
        );
        emit RequestedGameWinner(requestId);
    }
```

Here is the code I am using to test the contract:

```
it("works with live Chainlink Keepers and Chainlink VRF, we get a random winner", async function () {

                console.log("Setting up test...")
                const startingTimeStamp = await accountConnectedClone.getLatestTimeStamp()

                console.log("Setting up Listener...")
                await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  
                    accountConnected.once("WinnersPicked", async () => {
                        console.log("WinnersPicked event fired!")
                        try {
                            // add our asserts here
                            const recentWinners = await accountConnected.getWinners()
                            expect(recentWinners).to.exist
                            console.log(recentWinners)
                            assert(endingTimeStamp > startingTimeStamp)
                            resolve()
                        } catch (error) {
                            console.log(error)
                            reject(error)
                        }
                    })
                })
            })
```

Comment: Before i go through this, i just have one question. In what seems to be line 21, is the require commented out?

Comment: Yes, it's commented it out but it does work (I was able to call the function when it wasn't commented out). I should note that the contract which I want to use keepers with is a CLONED contract made with the OpenZeppelin Clones Library. I should also note that though I am able to call the perform upkeep function, it doesn't work. I tried testing to check if the 'gameState' changes to 'calculating' and it doesn't. I suspect it has something to do with the contract being a clone.

Comment: Hi @ethereumboy , which network are you using? Rinkeby and Kovan are deprecated. Keepers on these 2 networks are not going to call `performUpKeep` in your contract.